# Issue with Unreachable Code

Tags: java

trying to add goat to arraylist.  I wrote my errors in comments.
Arraylist could not be resolved to type.
 and Unreachable Code.

● If the character was already guessed, it should throw an IllegalArgumentException 
with a message saying the letter was already guessed

● If the character is not a letter from A­Z (borrow the if code from the Letter 
constructor ­ step 6 under Model Classes) , it should throw an 
IllegalArgumentException with a message saying the guess should be a letter 
from A­Z

```
package edu.htc.java1.phrasegame;
import edu.htc.java1.phrasegame.model.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PhraseGameController { 

    private Phrase currentPhrase; 
    private ArrayList<Character> guessed; 




    public boolean doPlayerGuess(Character play) {
      Character goat = Character.toUpperCase(play);
        if(guessed.contains(play)){
            throw new IllegalStateException("the letter was already guessed");}
            else if {String.valueOf(play).matches("[A-Z]"); 
            throw new IllegalStateException("the guess should be a letter from A­Z");

        }
        guessed.add(goat);  // Unreachable Code
        return currentPhrase.guessLetter(goat);

    }






    public PhraseGameController(){
    currentPhrase = new Phrase("This is only a test");
    guessed = new ArrayList<Character>();       ///Arraylist could not be resolved to Type
    }



     public Phrase getCurrentPhrase() {  
        return currentPhrase;
    }
    public void setCurrentPhrase(Phrase currentPhrase) {
        this.currentPhrase = currentPhrase;
    }

    public void setGuessed(ArrayList<Character> guessed) {
        this.guessed = guessed;
    }
    public ArrayList<Character> getGuessed() { 
        return guessed;
    }
}
```

..

> >
>
> ```
>  package edu.htc.java1.phrasegame.model;
> > 
> > import java.util.ArrayList;
> > 
> > public class Phrase {
> >         // public String phrase;    ArrayList<Letter> letters = new ArrayList<Letter>();    private String phrase;
> >     
> > 
> >     public Phrase(String phrase) {      phrase = phrase.toUpperCase(); ////
> > Problem         for(char c : phrase.toCharArray()) {            letters.add(new
> > Letter(c));         }       this.phrase = phrase;   }           public void
> > setPhrase(String phrase) {      this.phrase = phrase;   }
> > 
> >     public String getPhrase() {         return phrase;  }
> > 
> >     public ArrayList<Letter> getLetters() {         return letters;     }
> > 
> >     public boolean guessLetter(char c) {
> >             boolean foundLetter = false;
> >             
> >             // loop through your list of letters
> >             for(Letter l : letters){
> >                 // if list of letters contains same letter as the one you received then return true
> >                 if(l.getLetter() == c) {
> >                     l.unhide();
> >                     foundLetter = true;
> >                 }
> >             }
> > 
> >             // we did not find the letter, so we return false
> >             return foundLetter;         }   }
> ```

Comment: For your "ArrayList could not be resolved to type" issue, aren't you supposed to leave out the type when you create the object? guessed = new ArrayList<>(); Check out the way they use primitive types in collections here: [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)

Comment: Your code is unreachable because both the 'if' and the 'else' clauses throw exceptions. Since no matter what the input is, you've thrown an exception and therefore exited the method, no code that comes after the if/else is reachable.

Comment: I suppose it was just a Typo.  I have Arraylist.. when Actually ArrayList.  Thanks for making me look.

Comment: I don't follow you with the unreachable?   I'll edit it to show what I have now. @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas    Where could I incorporate guessed.add(goat)?

Comment: @user3381466 With your current code, as you have posted now, `guessed.add(goat)` is not unreachable. Where you currently have an `else if` you previously had `else`, which caused the line to be unreachable.

Answer (score 2):

```
else {String.valueOf(play).matches("[A-Z]");
```

This isn't doing what you think it does.

This is saying, if the value hasn't been guessed, then (always) see if play matches `A-Z`, ignore the result, then (in your next line) always throw an `IllegalStateException`.

So whatever happens at the moment, an IllegalStateExcetpion will always be thrown, and thus the return statement at the end of the method can never be reached.

You almost certainly want to wrap the above code in a second if statement, in a similar format to:

```
else if(otherThingToCheck()) {
    //Code to execute if otherThingToCheck() is true
}
```

Comment: If i do that. It tells me to delete the if.  although the unreachable code error is gone.

Comment: What tells you to delete the if? What exact message do you get?